# Epson SDK version2 Casher Drawer Open for Android?

Tags: java, android, sdk, epson

I am working on POS Project When i need to open cash drawer. I have tried by using EPSON SDK version2 for that.This SDK I can open printer connect and print stuffs receipt but can’t open casher drawer.How I can do it? Anyone please help me who know have idea for that.Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I'm can solve above my Question problem. The following answer :D <3

```
    mPrinter.setReceiveEventListener(this);
   try {

        mPrinter.addPulse(Printer.DRAWER_HIGH, Printer.PULSE_100);
        mPrinter.sendData(Printer.PARAM_DEFAULT);
    } catch (Epos2Exception e){

    }
```

Comment: hi Shujat , Thanks for your feedback comment.

Comment: Do you have any idea how we can achieve the same task in iOS?